# Magento 2.3: who knows how to place the cart summary into the static block on any page?

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I am trying to place the cart summary to the static page with products. I wanna locate it to the right from the grid of products (listed using Catalog Products widget). Anybody knows how to do this? Will appreciate if anybody can help.

Comment: My thought is you can think of other way to implement it. Any particular reason to use static block to render a mini cart in it?

Comment: @KazimNoorani I decided not to use default products listing provided by Magento for category pages. So I created cms blocks and listed all needed products via Catalog Products widget (applying all needed attributes). I removed the sidebar because it appears in the area under created cms block. So now I'd like to add the cart summary to the right of the area where I listed my products. I believe this will provide better experience for customers (add the products and see what they added with total amount). Do you have any alternative ideas how I can get the same outcome?